# Rails ActiveAdmin new resource form for object with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I have a many-to-many relationship set up between blog posts and blog categories using the has_many :through relationship and I am having trouble creating a blog post resource through active admin.

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :body, :created_at, :updated_at, :image_url, :title
  validates :body, :image_url, :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  has_many :blog_post_categorizations
  has_many :blog_categories, :through => :blog_post_categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_categories, allow_destroy: true
end

class BlogCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :blog_post_categorizations
  has_many :blog_posts, :through => :blog_post_categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_posts, allow_destroy: true
end

class BlogPostCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
  belongs_to :blog_category
end
```

Now as for my activeadmin formtastic setup, I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register BlogPost do
   form do |f|
    f.inputs "Blog Post" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :body, as: :html_editor
      f.input :image_url
    end
    f.inputs "Blog Categories" do
      f.has_many :blog_categories do |s|
        s.input :name
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

This allows the new blog post page to load successfully, but when I attempt to submit the new post with categories attached, it results in a "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: blog_categories_attributes" error.

I suspect that my models are set up properly, but the form in ActiveAdmin is not. Any ideas as to how I can correctly set up the form?

Additionally, included below is the blog_category data that's being sent in the params hash of the POST request

```
"blog_categories_attributes"=>{"1408936652467"=>{"name"=>"cooking"}, "1408936656066"=>{"name"=>"eat"}}
```

Using Rails version 3.2

Comment: Didn't you permit the params at all, or just forget to copy that part? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.1 and I believe permitted_params is for Rails 4